# django - XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace

Tags: python, xml, django

I get the following error -

```
XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
```

When trying to generate XML in django where the key contains a colon.  If I remove the : from the key there's no error.  Unfortunately the : needs to be there so I need to understand why the XML Parser is failing on the : and how to correct it.  I'm assuming I need to create a custom Parser.

Here's a sample of how the XML would look -

```
<entry>
    <id></id>
    <name></name>
    <source></source>
    <tes:variable>
        <tes:type></tes:type>
    </tes:variable>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with **django** but it seems as though you want a tag with a "**:**" (colon) in the name.

In XML, colons are valid for element names, but they designate a *namespace*.  So the XML parser thinks you are referring to an element named **variable** in the **tes** namespace.

But you have not indicated that you are using the **tes** namespace with a ***xmlns*** attribute, so the XML parser is unhappy ("prefix not bound to a namespace").  Removing the colon puts the element (now named **<tesvariable>**) back in the default namespace (no *prefix:*) so the parser is satisfied.

I think the simplest "solution" is just to have a ***xmlns*** attribute (**xmlns**="*namespaceURI*") in the **<entry>** element defining the **tes** namespace.  Then the XML parser should be satisfied.

W3Schools has some info on namespaces:
[XML Namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)